# HUE Hive/Impala SQL issue

Tags: select, hive, hiveql, impala, hue

I am trying to use Hue Hive/Impala select to find a time frame, what I got is

```
2017-02-22T17:47:54.00+00:00 2017-02-22T17:36:42.00+00:00 2017-02-22T17:33:08.00+00:00
```

all come with T, how can I change T to space like below:

```
2017-02-22 17:47:54.00+00:00
```

I am using select date_time from data

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: actually I want the result looks like:   2017-02-22 17:47:54

Comment: `select cast(concat(substr(TSTAMP_ISO_STRING, 1, 10), ' ', substr(TSTAMP_ISO_STRING, 12, 8)) as timestamp)
from
 (select '2017-02-22T17:47:54.00+00:00' as TSTAMP_ISO_STRING) x`

Comment: `select cast(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(TSTAMP_ISO_STRING, 'T',' '), '\\..*','') as timestamp)
from
 (select '2017-02-22T17:47:54.00+00:00' as TSTAMP_ISO_STRING) x`

Comment: Come on, this is really basic string processing shit...

Answer (score 0):

**Hive**

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-02-22T17:47:54.00+00:00',"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) as ts;
OK
ts
2017-02-22 17:47:54
```

**Impala**

```
> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-02-22T17:47:54.00+00:00',"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")) as ts;

+---------------------+
| ts                  |
+---------------------+
| 2017-02-22 17:47:54 |
+---------------------+
```